# Custom error popup for TextView/EditText in HoloEverywhere?

Tags: android, popup, textview, android-edittext, android-holo-everywhere

In HoloEverywhere, is there a way to change the background drawable of the popup which is triggered through `TextView.setError(...)`?

[image: Error popup]

Note: The default (non-HoloEverywhere) `TextView`/`EditText` uses internal resources for the popup and thus cannot be styled easily.

Answer (score 0):

You could extend `TextView` and override `setError()` by specifying to use another background image.

Comment: I would also have to override the complete popup handling. As indicated in the note at the bottom of my original question, popup handling and resources are completely internal. (If curious, have a look at the Android source code.)

Answer (score 0):

[public void setError (CharSequence error, Drawable icon)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setError%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29)

Comment: I was asking to modify the popup background (not the icon).

Comment: Okay, my bad. Don't think that's doable, you need a custom view.